# Make bootstrap table as small as possible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am trying to make bootstrap table as small as possible but based on the solutions of other questions, it is not working. I have tried `width:auto !important` or `table-layout:auto !important` but it is not working. Below is a sample of my table

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Though question is old but what I do to achieve this may help someone else. First you did not state version of bootstrap you are using. My solution worked for version four.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-sm">
......
</table>
```

Adding class responsive and sm did the magic for me the table in my went as low as to the content

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify special `width` for your rows or set width o table to current value?

Comment: can this be done dynamically with a css rule, i know this will work but but i'm seeking another way ?

Comment: you can try use css pseudo-classes and pseudo-selectors to choose first and last (in your case) rows. but you need to apply this to `th` and `td` elements

Answer (score 0):

Place the table inside a div and give width to that div. Aldo try to specify the width for td.